# Silex - Symfony Froms - How to wrap each radio button and its label in to separate div for each radio in choice list?

Tags: twig, symfony-forms, silex

I am using Silex micro faramework with Symfony forms. In twig templet I generate this field using :

```
...
{{ form_widget(form.transport_selection) }}
...
```

How can I overwrite this symfony twig form templet to generate wrap for each set (input field and label) in Silex.

This is my twig registration:

```
use Silex\Provider\FormServiceProvider;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\YamlFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => [
        __DIR__.'/App/View',
    ]
));
```

How to wrap radio button and label with div for each radio choice ?

**output:**

```
<div id="form_transport_selection">
  <input type="radio" id="form_transport_selection_0" name="form[transport_selection]" required="required" value="country" checked="checked">
  <label for="form_transport_selection_0" class="required">country</label>
  <input type="radio" id="form_transport_selection_1" name="form[transport_selection]" required="required" value="abroad">
  <label for="form_transport_selection_1" class="required">abroad</label>
</div>
```

**Expected output:**

```
<div id="form_transport_selection">
  <div class="radio1">
    <input type="radio" id="form_transport_selection_0" name="form[transport_selection]" required="required" value="country" checked="checked">
    <label for="form_transport_selection_0" class="required">country</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio2">
    <input type="radio" id="form_transport_selection_1" name="form[transport_selection]" required="required" value="abroad">
    <label for="form_transport_selection_1" class="required">abroad</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make new template for this form and redefine radio buttons view

my.form.twig

```
{% extends "form_div_layout.html.twig" %}

{%- block choice_widget_expanded -%}
    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
    {% set i=1 %}
    {%- for child in form %}
        <div class="radio-{{i}}">
            {{- form_widget(child) -}}
            {{- form_label(child, null, {translation_domain: choice_translation_domain}) -}}
        </div>
        {% set i=i+1 %}
    {% endfor -%}
    </div>
{%- endblock choice_widget_expanded -%}
```

and use it in controller template, where form is shown

```
{% form_theme form 'my.form.twig' %}
....
{{ form_widget(form.transport_selection) }}
```

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on MaxP's answer. Make sure to only modify this for radio buttons, you don't want this used in checkboxes! I've added a different class for checkboxes. Note the if/else to do this.

```
{% extends "form_div_layout.html.twig" %}

{% block choice_widget_expanded %}
<div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
    {% set i=1 %}
    {% for child in form %}
        {% if form.vars.multiple == false %}
        <div class="radio-{{i}}">
        {% elseif form.vars.multiple == true %}
        <div class="checkbox-{{i}}">
        {% endif %}
            {{ form_widget(child) }}
            {{ form_label(child, null, {translation_domain: choice_translation_domain}) }}
        </div>
        {% set i=i+1 %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock choice_widget_expanded %}
```

And use it in controller template, where form is shown

```
{% form_theme form 'my.form.twig' %}
....
{{ form_widget(form.transport_selection) }}
```

When using Symfony, I recommend overriding all Twig fields in app/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig

And then on config.yml you just need to make this available by adding it to twig's config

```
  twig:
      form_themes:
        - 'Form/fields.html.twig'
```